# Solving a circuit using Ohm's law and Kerchoff's laws

Tags: circuit-analysis

I feel I am missing some understanding about Kirchoff’s law and Ohm’s law. I was in the lab today and I didn’t get a chance to build the circuit in question, but I ran it in multisim later to test my answers and they were wrong. I am not sure I understand why, so below I have detailed the question and my steps to attempt to answer the question. Throughout the lab I was using a 9v battery with a 7.7v charge left, thus Vbatt = 7v.

[image]

1. Calculate the current through the loop using ohm’s law, combining the resistors into a single resistor for ease.

   \$I = V/R = 7.7V/1.3M\Omega = 5.5\mu A\$
2. Calculate the node voltages \$V_a\$, and \$V_b\$ using Ohm’s law.

   \$V_a = IR_1 = (5.5\mu A)(1M\Omega) =  5.5V\$
3. Calculate $V_b$ the same, this time R = \$R_1 + R_2\$

   \$V_b = I(R1 + R2) = (5.5\mu A)(1.1M\Omega) = 6.05V\$
4. Calculate the voltage drop using node voltages as reference

   \$V_1 = V_{batt} – V_a = 7.7v – 5.5v = 2.2v\$

   \$V_2 = V_b – V_a = .55V\$

   \$V_3 = V_b = 6.05\$

These answers are obviously wrong because V1, V2, and V3 must add to Vbatt according to Kirchoff’s loop law, but I don’t know what I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Va is not the voltage across R1. It's the sum of the voltages across R2 & R3. Vb is not the sum of the voltages across R1 & R2, it's the voltage across R3. Your calculations are assuming that the (+) end of Vbatt is your reference when you should be using the 'ground' point as your 0V.

Comment: R1 has the highest resistance so it must have the highest voltage across it.

Comment: Total R=1.4M not 1.3M.

Comment: @Rodo: looks like the 1.3M is a typo - current is right for 1.4 M.

Comment: @brhans that got it. Thank you for your help. If you would like to post your comment as an answer I will give you the credit for it. Also +1 for helping me understand and not just giving me the answers